# display more than just x, y, value in matplotlib chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

Have multi-dimension data,  for example:

[data pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILmAG.png)

when i plot x,y chart out. matplot gives the x,y coordinate info at the bottom right corner when one moves the cursor around. 
I am trying to add more info to the display, such as info1, info2 etc. on top of the x,y, either at the same corner, or popup when cursor moves on the chart.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use libraries Plotly and Cufflinks for interactive charts

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution: use a 3d plot, and use `color` and `size` arguments with respect to different values of your other variables. That way, you can display a lot of information very easily.

[image]